# Extract list of consecutive letter pairs from string

Tags: python

If I have a string e.g `hello bob` how can I split it so I can get a list of them like

```
['he', 'el', 'll', 'lo', 'o ', ' b', 'bo', 'ob']
```

including any spaces. I understand how to split it just into like `he`, `ll`,  `o` , etc. but I want to include every pair like what I said above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of **[List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)** and **[String slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html)** as below:

```py
s = 'hello bob'
res = [s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s)-1)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```py
['he', 'el', 'll', 'lo', 'o ', ' b', 'bo', 'ob']
```

Comment: Instead of the *Try this* pseudo text, what about sharing some explanation about the concepts/functions you are using here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this is just one line:

```
s = "hello bob"
[s[i]+s[i+1] for i,v in enumerate(s) if i+1 < len(s)]
```

output will be:

```
['he', 'el', 'll', 'lo', 'o ', ' b', 'bo', 'ob']
```

Comment: *just one line* -- Wouldn't it be better to have more than one line? When written this way, it is extremely difficult for beginners in this field to grasp all the concepts involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` for that task following way:

```
text = "hello bob"
pairs = [''.join(i) for i in zip(text[:-1], text[1:])]
print(pairs)
```

Output:

```
['he', 'el', 'll', 'lo', 'o ', ' b', 'bo', 'ob']
```

Explanation: I `zip` (i.e. create 2-tuples from corresponding elements) from `hello bo` and `ello bob` then turn them into `str`s by joining elements of each 2-tuple.